# How do I use credit from a cancelled trip on American Airlines?

Tags: tickets, american-airlines

I booked a "flexible" trip via AA and then cancelled it, they sent me an email with a ticket number for the credit for that trip.

I'm trying to book a new trip now and there is no field to enter the old ticket number before entering my credit card details and I would rather not pay for one more trip and then have to spend another two hours on the phone to get a refund.

Is the only way via phone booking?

Comment: Have you checked [this page](https://www.aa.com/i18n/customer-service/payment-options/travel-credit.jsp)? How you redeem and related restrictions depend on the type of credit, apparently. Also are you logged into your AA account?

Comment: @jcaron I don't have an AAadvantage account but I shouldn't need it. According to the table I'll have to call since it's a non-us flight. Thanks.

Comment: Lesson learned - never flying AA again. What a mess.